# Error on installing the magento on windows 10 using wamp server

Tags: php, magento, wamp

I am trying to install magento in my windows pc using wamp server.

Everything I have set but when I go to "localhost" and click on "magento" under my project then it sends to me on URL "http:// magento/" that gives me error

> "Server not found"

I think when I click on magento under my project it should send me to

magento/index.php/install/

my magento is in

> "C:\wamp\www\magento"

Comment: Is it magento 2 or lower version ?

Comment: make sure you installed wamp properly......

Comment: it is magento 2 @DeepKakkar

Comment: wamp is installed properly, it is green and working...@fresher

Comment: https://www.ubertheme.com/docs/install-magento-2-localhost/

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you activated **rewrite** module on apache wamp server

if it's not activated, you can add this line in httpd.conf file

`LoadModule rewrite_module modules/mod_rewrite.so`

Answer (score 0):

everything is right and properly installed....
just need to enter right url... that is

> http://localhost/magento/setup/